# Is it possible to change the measurement unit in QGIS 3.2 for the select features by radius tool?

Tags: qgis-3, measurements, units

Is it possible to set the default units for the select features by radius tool?

I believe the default is set to meters but I can not seem to get it to use kilometers or miles for example. I know you can set the default units for the measure tool under Settings > Options > Map Tools but this does not effect the units in the selection tool.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually these tools get their measuring units from the projection, so you can either have m or degree. m to km is no hassle, m to miles is weird, and degree to anything comprehensible is almost impossible. So stick with m.

Comment: Its just not convenient when selecting features at a larger scale range

Comment: Define "larger scale".

Comment: 1:200,000 and greater

Comment: But how much inconvenience is it to type three additional zeros? Also, how often do you need to select features more than 100 km distant?

Comment: I was only looking to find out whether this can be done or not, QGIS allows you to change units elsewhere so I was wondering if this was consistence across it. Thanks anyway